# reinserting italics after transfering from .doc to .txt and back to .doc

Tags: microsoft-word-2011

I have a 90k word doc that I want to clean up the formatting on. To do this, I want to convert the .doc into a .txt file. All easy so far. Trouble is, I have about 600 instances of italics. So when I put the change the .txt back to .doc, I want to be able to easily get the italics back.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Scott

Comment: Are there specific words or phrases that need to be italicised, or some other way to identify them within the plain text?

Comment: Saving a .doc file as .txt removes all formatting from the document.  I would just clean up the document by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If there are specific words that you can search for, you can do find and replace with formatting.  In the Replace dialog, click on "More>>" then near the bottom is a "Format" button.  Click that and select Font, then Font Style Italic, and click OK.  Now, under the "Replace with" field it should say "Font: Italic".  You can then search for your word, replace it with the same word, and it will be italicized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide on a string that doesn't appear anywhere else in the the document, such as **{it}**. Then under **Find and Replace** and **More>>**, in the Find box choose Format -> Font -> Italic, then Special -> Any Character: this will appear as **^?** in the Find box. Then in the Replace box enter your reserved string and Special -> Find What Text: this will show with the above reserved string as **{it}^&**.

When you Replace All you will have **{it}** in front of each italicised character, and this will be saved in your text file and restored when you re-import into word. Then you restore the italics by finding **{it}** and then Special -> Any Character, to give **{it}^?** in the Find box. Now in the Replace box set Format -> Text -> Italics and Special -> Find What Text. This will italicise all your original characters again, with **{it}** preceding each.

Now all you have to do is to replace **{it}** with empty text and you should now have all your original italics in place.

NB I tested this with an earlier version of Word, so some of the UI labels could be slightly different.